# How to batch rename images in several folders?

Tags: image, matlab

I have 600 images (e.g. `images_0, images_1, images_2, ..., images_599`) which are saved in 12 folders (e.g. `dataset_1, dataset_2, dataset_3, ..., dataset_12`).

I am currently using this code to rename images:

```
mainDirectory = 'C:\Users\Desktop\data';
subDirectory = dir([mainDirectory '/dataset_*']);
for m = 1 : length(subDirectory)
    subFolder = dir(fullfile(mainDirectory, subDirectory(m).name, '*.png'));
    fileNames = {subFolder.name};
    for iFile = 1 : numel( subFolder )
        newName = fullfile(mainDirectory, subDirectory(m).name, sprintf('%00d.png', iFile));
        movefile(fullfile(mainDirectory, subDirectory(m).name, fileNames{iFile}), newName);
    end
end
```

This code works well but I want to change the format of `newName` to the following: `number-of-dataset_name-of-image` (e.g. `1_images_0`, `1_images_1`, `2_images_0`, `2_images_1`, etc.). How can I make this change to `newName`?

Comment: You just need to modify the `sprintf` call. Is this your code?

Comment: that is the question, How Can I change the expression in the line newName. No, it is not my code.  please help me, I m new in matlab.

Comment: Try reading [the documentation for `sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) and attempting the problem on your own first.

Answer (score 2):

You can first split your folder name to get the 1 to 12 number

```
str = strsplit('dataset_12', '_');     % split along '_'
```

The folder number will be in `str{2}`.

Then concatenate this piece of information with

```
new_name = [str{2} '_' original_image_name]
```

where `original_image_name` is the original image name (!) - or use alternatively `sprintf`as you already did.